# How to manage time zones across multiple systems in java?

Tags: java, timezone

I have a web application that returns a booking time based on the country where the event was performed.

Eg: If the booking was created in **India** at `02-JUNE-2020 1700 IST`,then time returned is:

```
2020-06-02T17:00:00+0530
```

If the booking was created in **Thailand** at `02-JUNE-2020 1700` Thai Time,then time returned is:

```
2020-06-02T17:00:00+0700
```

Now I have to store all this in a system in UK time,so the data would be:
for **India**,in UK system:  `2020-06-02T12:30:00+0100`
for **Thailand**,in UK system:  `2020-06-02T11:00:00+0100`

I know I can use the zone indicator of +0530 to convert to milliseconds offset by using

```
TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(milliseconds);
```

and find the corresponding timezone to do a reverse integration.
But is there an easy way to translate the IST to UK time directly in java ?

Answer (score 1):

`+0530` is not actually indicative of any particular time zone. A time zone could be, say, `Europe/Amsterdam`. This is `+0100` in winter and `+0200` in summer, and the zone `Europe/Paris` has the exact same offset at the exact same dates. Whilst unlikely, it is entirely possible that 5 years from now this is no longer the case. Note that `+0100` does not accurately describe `Europe/Amsterdam` (it'd be wrong in summer), and cannot disambiguate between amsterdam and paris, which is why it's not good enough, generally. If this is just what you've been given and you can't change it, yea, getAvailableIDs is one way to at least attempt to convert `+0530` into a zone, but note that usually you get many answers, so I don't know how you'd figure out how to pick the 'right' zone. Consider changing the system so that you get this timezone, the full ID, as part of the input instead.

Let's say you have obtained the zone, somehow.

Given `2020-06-02T17:00:00+0530` - you can translate this to the exact moment in time that the event being described by this timestamp has/will occur. That's presumably important; if you want an alarm to go off at that time anywhere on the planet you can now make that happen. That you store this 'in UK time' is just an implementation detail, that doesn't matter: You're storing the *instant* in time this event occurs, and not the way the human-oriented system that created this timestamp would refer to it (which is, presumably: '5 in the evening, on the second of june in 2020, in india').

But, you indicate a need to convert back from this 'exact instant in time' back to the zoned time.

Why?

If the answer is: So that it is familiar to the human, because the human I will end up printing this string to is definitely in india, you potentially have some issues if you go with the not-human-relevant zone ID of '+0530'; you optimally want to go with the more human-relevant zone ID of 'Asia/Kolkata', for example.

### Okay, and now in java please!

an instant in time is best represented with an instance of `java.time.Instant`. This has no timezone info; it just marks a moment in time. (internally it stores as UTC, but that is an implementation detail. these things are timezoneless).

Once you have an Instant, and you have a TimeZone, you can do:

```
Instant x = ....; // obtain an instance somehow.
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"); // get a zone somehow.
ZonedDateTime zdt = x.atZone(zone);
```

You can print a zdt, for example with a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` instance, and it'll render it as somebody in india would prefer.

If you have instead stored, say, a string containing the text `2020-06-02T12:30:00+0100`, you can go from there to an instant rather easily, and then you can `.atZone` your way back to indian time.